# Misleading position results on Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, google-ranking

When I look at search console to check my rankings, I see I am ranking 1st or 2nd pages (position column) for some keywords but the truth is I am not. I even go as far as the 15th page but I can't see my website there. Why is the **position** column showing misleading results?

Comment: Just to clarify, the "position" column is _supposed to_ indicate the average position in the SERPs, not the "page" the result appears on. Also, when checking this yourself use "Privacy browsing" to ensure your search preferences are not taken into account. Also, make sure you are searching on the same locality, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to make a neutral search as much as I can but its claiming that I am on the first page is far from the truth.

Comment: Have you experienced any kind of drop in organic traffic recently that would perhaps suggest that your ranking has dropped?

Comment: No, I haven't noticed.

Comment: to iwsnmw , I have the same experience, maybe it is connected with that I use the same browser browsing search console and querying on google. But in second browser (not connected with my google account) now I see results are comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Google Search Engine Console position option isn't only for Keywords but also it can be link sections, carousels, Knowledge Graph cards, and many other types of result features.

For details please visit: 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7042828#position